# My autocomplete field is not working with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete

I'm working on a project and had an autocomplete field for a form working fine (autocompletes the countries, it's a travel website) but since we merged everything together the autocomplete doesn't work for some reason.

The initial autocomplete code is from w3schools and isn't bootstrap, however my form was bootstrap and it worked fine pre merge.

I tried bringing in an untouched bootstrap example into my code and it didn't work either so there's definitely something that is preventing it from working. Below is my code, sorry about including all of it but I think the problem might be hidden somewhere else since bringing in the unchanged demo didn't work either.

html page:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vacation Package</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stephen_style.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <script src="Stephen_packages_script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-header d-flex col">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Travel<b>Experts</b></a>
                <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse"
                    class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggler ml-auto">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a href="vPackagesForm" class="nav-link">Vacation Packages</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Hotel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Car Rentals</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cruise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Tours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Yacht/Boat Charters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Attractions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="register" class="nav-link">Login/Register</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto">
                    <li class="navbar-form-wrapper">
                    <form class="navbar-form form-inline navbar-right">
                        <div class="input-group search-box">
                            <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here...">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>
                <form class="form form-inline justify-content-center" method="post" action="/vPackages_form" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="autocomplete">
                        <label for="dateLeaving">Date Leaving:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="dateLeaving" name="dateLeaving" class="form-control " required="true" />

                        <label for="dateReturning">Date Returning:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="dateReturning" name="dateReturning" class="form-control " required="true" />
                        <input type="text" id="leavingFrom" name="leavingFrom" class="form-control " required="true"
                            placeholder="Leaving From" />
                        <select id="vacaPackage" name="vacaPackage" class="form-control " required="true"
                            placeholder="Choose Your Package" />
                        <option value="caribbean">Caribbean New Year</option>
                        <option value="polynesia">Polynesian Paradise</option>
                        <option value="asia">Asian Expedition</option>
                        <option value="europe">European Vacation</option>
                        </select>
                        <input data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"
                        value="Add Package"></input>
                    </div>

                </form>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Congrats! You are on your way to paradise!</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Start Your Journey!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="caribbeanCSS">
                <h3><%= packages[0].PkgName %></h3>
                <p class="black"> <%= packages[0].PkgDesc%></p>
                <p>Start Date: <%= packages[0].PkgStartDate.toDateString() %></p>
                <p>End Date: <%= packages[0].PkgEndDate.toDateString() %></p><br />
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="caribbeanVideo()">See Video</button><br />
                <h4 class="black">Package Base Price:</h4>
                <h2 class="blue">$<%= packages[0].PkgBasePrice%></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="polyCSS">
                <h3><%= packages[1].PkgName %></h3>
                <h5 class="black"><%= packages[1].PkgDesc%></h5>
                <p>Start Date: <%= packages[1].PkgStartDate.toDateString() %></p>
                <p>End Date: <%= packages[1].PkgEndDate.toDateString() %></p><br />
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="polyVideo()">See Video</button><br />
                <h4>Package Base Price: </h4>
                <h2 class="blue">$<%= packages[1].PkgBasePrice%></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="asiaCSS">
                <h3><%= packages[2].PkgName %></h3>
                <p class="black"><%= packages[2].PkgDesc%></p>
                <p>Start Date: <%= packages[2].PkgStartDate.toDateString() %></p>
                <p>End Date: <%= packages[2].PkgEndDate.toDateString() %></p><br />
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="asiaVideo()">See Video</button><br />
                <h4>Package Base Price: </h4>
                <h2 class="blue">$<%= packages[2].PkgBasePrice%></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6" id="europeCSS">

                <h3><%= packages[3].PkgName %></h3>
                <h5 class="black"><%= packages[3].PkgDesc%></h5>
                <p>Start Date: <%= packages[3].PkgStartDate.toDateString() %></p>
                <p>End Date: <%= packages[3].PkgEndDate.toDateString() %></p><br />
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="europeVideo()">See Video</button><br />
                <h4>Package Base Price: </h4>
                <h2 class="blue">$<%= packages[3].PkgBasePrice%></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <hr>
        Copyright &copy; 2019
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

my css:

```
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
}
body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
  url('./media/vacation.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 110px;
}
.navbar-header.col {
padding: 0 !important;
}   
.navbar {       
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.nav-link img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: -8px 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand b {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eb5844;
}
.navbar ul.nav li a:hover, .navbar ul.nav li a:focus {
  color: #f08373 !important;
}
.navbar ul.nav li.active a, .navbar ul.nav li.active a:hover, .navbar ul.nav li.active a:focus {
  color: #eb5844 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 1px solid #eb5844;
}
.search-box {
  position: relative;
}   
.search-box input.form-control {        
  padding-right: 140px;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.search-box input.form-control:focus {      
  border-color: #f08373;        
}
.search-box .input-group-addon {
  min-width: 35px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 7px;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar .nav-item a {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.search-box i {
  color: #a0a5b1;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.navbar .nav-item i {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.navbar .dropdown-item i {
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 22px;
}
.navbar .nav-item.open > a {
  background: none !important;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #777;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  line-height: normal;
}
.navbar .navbar-form {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}
.form-inline {
  margin: 80px 0 30px 0;
}
.form-elegant .font-small {
  font-size: 0.8rem; 
}
.form-elegant .z-depth-1a {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(55, 161, 255, 0.26), 0 4px 12px 0 rgba(121, 155, 254, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(55, 161, 255, 0.26), 0 4px 12px 0 rgba(121, 155, 254, 0.25); 
}
.form-elegant .z-depth-1-half, .form-elegant .btn:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(85, 182, 255, 0.28), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(36, 133, 255, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(85, 182, 255, 0.28), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(36, 133, 255, 0.15); 
}
.button {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
}
.autocomplete {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 72%;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid ;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.banner{
  color: white;
  background-image: url('media/positanobanner.jpg');
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav a:link, #bottomNavLinks a:link {
  color:darkblue;
}
#nav a:hover, #bottomNavLinks a:hover {
  color:#ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav a:active {
  color:#f0f0f0;
  background-color:#00ff00;
}
#caribbeanCSS {
  border-style: ridge;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("media/caribbean.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  }
#polyCSS {
  border-style: ridge;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("media/poly.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  }
#asiaCSS {
  border-style: ridge;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("media/asia.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  }
#europeCSS {
  border-style: ridge;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("media/europe.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  }
#bottomNav {
  color: black;
  position: absolute; 
  right: 45%;
  top: 97%;
  }
#footer {
  margin-top: 200px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120%;
  left: 45%;
}
.blue {
  color:blue;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.black {
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 265%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 185%;
}
```

my javascript:

````
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
    the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
    var currentFocus;

    /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;

        /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) { return false;}
        currentFocus = -1;

        /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

        /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

        /*for each item in the array...*/
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

          /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
          if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

            /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
            b = document.createElement("DIV");

            /*make the matching letters bold:*/
            b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
            b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

            /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

            /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
            b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                closeAllLists();
            });

            a.appendChild(b);
          }
        }
    });
};

/*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
    };
});

function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;

    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
};

function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    };
};

function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
        };
    };
};

/*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});


/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("leavingFrom"), countries);


//Preview videos for vacation package
function caribbeanVideo() 
{
    window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trmEq3e04a4")
}

function polyVideo() 
{
        window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ9E-Jadv88")
}

function asiaVideo() 
{
    window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBMBixI40Nw")
}

function europeVideo() 
{
    window.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfEiKK-iX70")
}```
````